# Foundation 5 Dropdown Top Bar not working in WordPress

Tags: navigation, dropdown, framework

I made a 'first version' of a site with help of foundation 5. Now I'm trying to convert it to a WordPress (3.8) template. Most problems have been easily solved, but I can't get the Top Bar to work.

At first it wouldn't work at all. With the help of google and earlier answers I fixed the normal menu with https://gist.github.com/awshout/3943026 
and the mobile menu with http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/304-foundation-5-topbar-mobile-navigation

My only problem left is the dropdown menu. The dropdown still doesn't work. If I click on it, the button does turn dark, but no dropdown menu appears.

Comment: Please provide more details and preferably live example of the issue.

Comment: @Rarst♦ Live example is hard, because it's on my mamp. This is the code it outputs for the menu. http://paste2.org/cw49kGCm